# Why does Slater's condition require a point in the *relative* interior of the domain?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Consider a convex optimisation problem in the standard form: $\min f_0(\mathbf x)$ subject to $f_i(\mathbf x)\le 0$ and $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$, with $f_i$ all convex functions.

When discussing Slater's condition, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_condition) mentions (if I understand it correctly) that Slater's conditions state that strong duality holds if there's a point $\mathbf x^*$ in the *relative* interior of the intersection of the domains of the constraint functions corresponding to which all inequality constraints are satisfied with strict inequality.

Why do we need a point in the *relative* interior of the domain here? What fails if we just ask for an interior point?
Some simple examples would probably help to make this point clear.